# Effect of destruction of stock depository on stock holdings

Tags: india, stock-markets

If in a war Mumbai (including [NSDL](https://nsdl.co.in/faqs/faq.php) and CDSL) is destroyed, will all my stock holdings disappear (so that my investments are gone without serious hopes of recovery)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If in a war Mumbai (including NSDL and CDSL) is destroyed, will all my stock holdings disappear

Short Answer NO. Your investments are safely kept.
This is no different from what happens to your money kept in bank, its just an electronic entry and the server crashes.

There are multiple levels:

- Both NSDL and CSDL are well managed. They have a active DR site where the data is stored, so incase of issue with one center, there is active back-up at other site.
- Every Depository Participant, stores information about his clients. For example one cannot directly open an account with NSDL/CSDL. He has to go via a depository participant [say HDFC/ICICI/SBI]. These participants maintain a local snapshot of account they hold. So even if NSDL goes down, if we add statements from all DP's it would get the full set of NSDL.
- Every Company maintains a periodic copy of all the investors. This is slightly dated. The company uses this for dividend distribution and other notices that need to be sent to shareholders. So even if NSDL and the DP's go-down together, which is very unlikely; one can still get this slightly older data from companies. Then using the data set from NSE/BSE, one can find out what transactions took place and re-construct the entire statement.

And no you don't need a war to destroy. Any Hardware can [and does] routinely crash and strong backup/archive/restore policy and procedures are in place.

Comment: Thank you. For war recovery, DR site has to be remote - away from mumbai. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes DR are never in same location. They are quite apart.

Answer (score 1):

One would hope that there are electronic and/or paper backups of all records being held off-site somewhere else just in case of a natural or man-made disaster.  The financial institutions here in the U.S. have an impressive array of backup systems and disaster recovery plans in the eventuality of something bad happening.

That being said, there's no such thing as a perfect system, so there can always be the *chance* (however small) that even backups, remote offsite storage and other recovery methods could fail, so nothing can be absolutely counted on.

If you can't confirm that there is such a backup plan in place for your holdings then maybe you'd be better off moving your investments to an exchange/country that can provide some level of protection.